# Converting Associative Array to Numerical to write in Sheet in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write pull a directory that is provided in JSON to a Google Spreadsheet.

I am able to get the JSON and write the fields but I am stuck on writing the employee data to the sheet. The JSON provides an Associative array. From my understanding to use `Range.setValues()` you need to have a Numerical Array.

[image: I get this. In the Logger the Array says null]

I am able to write the field titles into the first row of the Google Sheet.

The code I am using to write the employee data is:

```
function writeJSONtoSheet(json, sheetId) {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheets()[0];

  var header = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, json['fields'].length+1); //A1 to O1
  var headerVals = header.getValues();
  var newColsTitles = ["ID #"];
  var newColsIndex = ["id"];

  for (var i = 0; i < json['fields'].length; i++){
    newColsTitles.push(json['fields'][i]['name']);
    newColsIndex.push(json['fields'][i]['id'])
  }

  header.setValues([newColsTitles]);
  var employeeRows = sheet.getRange(2,1,json['employees'].length,json['fields'].length+1);
  var employees = [];
  var empArr = [];
  var emps = [];
  for (var e = 0; e < json['employees'].length; e++) {
    employees.push(json['employees'][e]);
  }
  for (var y = 0; y < employees.length; y++){
    for (var x = 0; x < newColsIndex.length; x++){
      empArr[y] = [];
      empArr[y][x] = employees[y][newColsIndex[x]];
      console.log(employees[y][newColsIndex[x]])
    }
  }
  employeeRows.setValues(empArr);

}
```

When I log`employees[y][newColsIndex[x]]` inside the Loop it loops correctly over each employees fields.

The JSON format is the following:

```
{
"fields": [
    {
        "id": "displayName",
        "type": "text",
        "name": "Display Name"
    },
    {
        "id": "firstName",
        "type": "text",
        "name": "First Name"
    },
    {
        "id": "lastName",
        "type": "text",
        "name": "Last Name"
    },
    {
        "id": "gender",
        "type": "text",
        "name": "Gender"
    },
    {
        "id": "jobTitle",
        "type": "list",
        "name": "Job Title"
    },
    {
        "id": "workPhone",
        "type": "text",
        "name": "Work Phone"
    },
    {
        "id": "workPhoneExtension",
        "type": "text",
        "name": "Work Extension"
    },
    {
        "id": "skypeUsername",
        "type": "text",
        "name": "Skype Username"
    },
    {
        "id": "facebook",
        "type": "text",
        "name": "Facebook URL"
    }
],
"employees": [
    {
        "id":123,
        "displayName":"John Doe",
        "firstName":"John",
        "lastName":"Doe",
        "gender":"Male",
        "jobTitle":"Customer Service Representative",
        "workPhone":"555-555-5555",
        "workPhoneExtension":null,
        "skypeUsername":"JohnDoe",
        "facebook":"JohnDoeFacebook"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Shouldn't you create the employee row to write outside of the loop where you create the columns in that row?

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing with the loop and then the nested loops that are separated?

Comment: The code isn't complete. (there isn't a var statement for newColsIndex)

Comment: Debug the nested loop and you'll see what I mean. Use `console.log(empArr)` and view in Stackdriver. @Ruben, it comes from the code OP uses to successfully write the column headers.

Comment: I updated with the full code @Rubén. When I consloe.log and view in stackdriver it logs each value for each employee as I am expecting. I think my error is in writing it to the Array so that it is in the proper format for the setValues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
for (var y = 0; y < employees.length; y++){
    for (var x = 0; x < newColsIndex.length; x++){
      empArr[y] = [];
      empArr[y][x] = employees[y][newColsIndex[x]];
      console.log(employees[y][newColsIndex[x]])
    }
```

to (see inline comments)

```
for (var y = 0; y < employees.length; y++){
    empArr.push([]);// inserts a new row for each employee
    for (var x = 0; x < newColsIndex.length; x++){
      //empArr[y] = []; // this was reseting the array on each pass
      empArr[y][x] = employees[y][newColsIndex[x]];
      console.log(employees[y][newColsIndex[x]])
    }
```